# Ruby & Rules Engines

Tags: ruby, rule-engine

I'm looking for a simple way to let users define a set of rules to filter objects.

Eg. let them define something like "notify me about a booking if booking date < 2009/04/30 AND value > 100.00"

More or less: I'd like to have a Ruby rules engine with custom DSL.

Is there a library offering that? Came across Ruleby, but it doesn't support custom DSL, yet.

What's the best apporach to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Treetop](http://cjheath.github.io/treetop/).  You can define your DSL as a Parsing Expression Grammar and then parse it to create your rules in whatever format you like.

Comment: Hi

thanks for answer. Treetop really looks like a solution. 
Do you have a link for any best practices website maybe? Hard to find good stuff on the net.

I was thinking about the following approach:
- Let users define their rules
- Parse these using Treetop
- Create Ruby code based on these rules 
- feed these into Ruleby
- filter my objects using the rules engine

Does that sound too freaky?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't had much luck finding resources on Treetop either.  But your solution sounds like the right approach.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [wongi-engine](https://github.com/ulfurinn/wongi-engine) gem it is a new rules engine based on the Rete algorithm that is gathering a fair bit of attention lately.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how and on what objects these rules should be evaluated, but if these are ActiveRecord models maybe [Ambition](http://ambition.rubyforge.org/) would be way to go. It let's you write conditions in ruby, something like:

```
User.select { |m| m.name == 'jon' && m.age == 21 }
```

This gets converted to SQL and you'll get all users satisfying the given criteria

Comment: It looks nice but it is no longer maintained.