# Specifying and Executing Rules in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, event-handling, rule-engine

I am looking for a Ruby/Rails tool that will help me accomplish the following:

I would like to store the following string, and ones similar to it, in my database. When an object is created, updated, deleted, etc., I want to run through all the strings, check to see if the CRUD event matches the conditions of the string, and if so, run the actions specified.

```
When a new ticket is created and it's category=6 then notify user 1234 via email
```

I am planning to create an interface that builds these strings, so it doesn't need to be a human-readable string. If a JSONish structure is better, or a tool has an existing language, that would be fantastic. I'm kinda thinking something along the lines of:

```
{
  object_types: ['ticket'],
  events: ['created', 'updated'],
  conditions:'ticket.category=6',
  actions: 'notify user',
  parameters: {
    user:1234,
    type:'email'
  }
}
```

So basically, I need the following:

1. **Monitor CRUD events** - It would be nice if the tool had a way to do this, but Ican use Rails' ModelObservers here if the tool doesn't natively provide it
2. **Find all matching "rules"** - This is my major unknown...
3. **Execute the requested method/parameters** - Ideally, this would be defined in my Ruby code as classes/methods

Are there any existing tools that I should investigate?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the responses so far guys! I really appreciate you pointing me down the right paths.

The use case here is that we have many different clients, with many different business rules. For the rules that apply to all clients, I can easily create those in code (using something like Ruleby), but for all of the client-specific ones, I'd like to store them in the database. Ideally, the rule could be written once, stored either in the code, or in the DB, and then run (using something Resque for performance).

At this point, it looks like I'm going to have to roll my own, so any thoughts as to the best way to do that, or any tools I should investigate, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you just use callbacks like `after_create` and `after_update` for this?

Comment: @mischa - In a way, yes. Each one of those should fire an event, then something else should process the event looking for matching rules, and if it finds any, execute the actions on those rules. Abstracting it nicely so that I don't have to manually fire the events and do the rule matching would be nice though :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it would be a major thing to write something yourself to do this, I don't know of any gems which would do this (but it would be good if someone wrote one!)

I would tackle the project in the following way, the way I am thinking is that you don't want to do the rule matching at the point the user saves as it may take a while and could interrupt the user experience and/or slow up the server, so...

1. Use observers to store a record each time a CRUD event happens, or to make things simpler use the [Acts as Audited gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited) which does this for you.

1.5. Use a rake task, running from your crontab to run through the latest changes, perhaps every minute, or you could use [Resque](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque) which does a good job of handling lots of jobs

2. Create a set of tables which define the possible rules a user could select from, perhaps something like

Table: Rule

Name

ForEvent  (eg. CRUD)

TableInQuestion

- FieldOneName
- FieldOneCondition etc.

MethodToExecute

You can use a bit of metaprogramming to execute your method and since your method knows your table name and record id then this can be picked up.

**Additional Notes**

The best way to get going with this is to start simple then work upwards.  To get the simple version working first I'd do the following ...

1. Install acts as audited
2. Add an additional field to the created audit table, :when_processed
3. Create yourself a module in your /lib folder called something like processrules which roughly does this

   3.1 Grabs all unprocessed audit entries
   3.2 Marks them as processed (perhaps make another small audit table at this point to record events happening)
4. Now create a rules table which simply has a name and condition statement, perhaps add a few sample ones to get going

   Name: First | Rule Statement: 'SELECT 1 WHERE table.value = something'
5. Adapt your new processrules method to execute that sql for each changed entry (perhaps you want to restrict it to just the tables you are working with)
6. If the rule matched, add it to your log file.

From here you can extrapolate out the additional functionality you need and perhaps ask another question about the metaprogramaming side of dynamically calling methods as this question is quite broad, am more than happy to help further.

I tend to think the best way to go about task processing is to setup the process nicely first so it will work with any server load and situation then plug in the custom bits.

Comment: +1 - Thanks for bringing up Resque. I have looked at it for other things in the past, but it didn't occur the me how useful it would be for this situation. I also think you are right that rolling my own may be faster/better than trying to hack an existing solution to make it work. I look forward to any more feedback you can provide!

Comment: I've added some additional notes to help you get cracking, perhaps give those ideas a try and ask some new questions as and when you get stuck on a process and either myself or someone else will be very happy help out with some actual code.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and giving additional information! I appreciate you putting the time into this. Accepted/bounty rewarded :-)

Have an awesome day!

Answer (score 3):

You could make this abstract enough so that you can specify arbitrary conditions and rules, but then you'd be developing a framework/engine as opposed to solving the specific problems of your app.

There's a good chance that using [ActiveRecord::Observer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html) will solve your needs, since you can hardcode all the different types of conditions you expect, and then only put the unknowns in the database. For example, say you know that you'll have people watching categories, then create an association like `category_watchers`, and use the following Observer:

```
class TicketObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  # observe :ticket # not needed here, since it's inferred by the class name

  def after_create(ticket)
    ticket.category.watchers.each{ |user| notify_user(ticket, user) }
  end

  # def after_update ... (similar)

  private

  def notify_user(ticket, user)
    # lookup the user's stored email preferences
    # send an email if appropriate
  end
end
```

If you want to store the email preference along with the fact that the user is watching the category, then use a join model with a flag indicating that.

If you then want to abstract it a step further, I'd suggest using something like treetop to generate the observers themselves, but I'm not convinced that this adds more value than abstracting similar observers in code.

Comment: +1 - Thanks for the response Ben. The big deal for me is that these rules may be specific to each client, so I can't store all of my rules in code. Or more specifically, I can't assume that all rules should be run for all clients. This opened up a new idea...perhaps I should define all of the rules in code, but have something in the database that specifies which rules are run. Thanks for your thoughts; this has opened my eyes a little bit more!

Answer (score 2):

There's a [Ruby & Rules Engines SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820259/ruby-rules-engines) that might have some info that you might find useful. There's another Ruby-based rules engine that you may want to explore that as well - [Ruleby](https://github.com/Codalytics/ruleby).

Hope that this helps you start your investigation.

Comment: +1 - Thanks JW, I actually started there, but for some reason I never found the documentation for Ruleby. I appreciate you pointing me to it!