# ruby rules engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dsl

I feel like that I am about to reinvent the wheel here, so before I do that ...

I have a large set of data that I need to process, and the 'rules' that process the data will evolve over time, so I thought that implementing a simple rules engine would be in order.

Note **I am not looking for a natural language parser**, I want all of the rules to be ruby procs.

I could imagine the syntax to look something like:

```
engine = SimpleRulesEngine.new

rule = engine.add_rule(priority: 10) do |row|
  row.name != 'George'
end

rule.action do |row|
  puts "Yikes, name is not George!, it was #{row.name}"
  row.update_attribute :name, 'George'
end

engine.process collection
```

I was wondering if there was any existing patterns or gems out there that would help with this.  The one that seems closest is [ruleby](https://github.com/codalytics/ruleby), but does not seem to be actively maintained, and seems too complex of a solution for my problem.

Thanks!

---

Note this is a similar question to : [Ruby & Rules Engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820259/ruby-rules-engines), but different in that, I do not care about natural language processing, and rule storage.

Comment: Without more details it's difficult to help; so far it just looks like you have a "rule should fire" block, and a "rule action" block. Seems like a straight-forward DSL at most, and some reasonably-clear Ruby even if you ignore a thin DSL wrapper.

Comment: You might want to check out gem state_machine

Comment: @DaveNewton, i think your exactly right.  Below is the solution that I came up with.  Thanks for pushing me in the right direction

Answer (score 7):

@DaveNewton talked some sence into me, and it is clear that basically I was looking for some simple DSL for my app, this is what I ended up using -- its very simple, but incase it is useful for someone else:

```
# /lib/simple_rules_engine
# To use, just include it in any file where you need some rules engine love ...
# then defile rules like so:
#
# rule :name_of_rule,
#       priority: 10,
#       validate: lambda {|o| # do something with o}
#       fail: lambda {|o| o.fail!}} 
# 
# then to run the engine
# process_rules(your_data_set)
#   
module SimpleRulesEngine
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    class_attribute :rules
    self.rules = []
  end

  module ClassMethods

    # rule :name_of_rule,
    #       priority: 10,
    #       validate: lambda {|o| # do something with o}
    #       fail: lambda {|o| o.fail!}}
    def rule(name,options={})
      self.rules << SimpleRulesEngine::Rule.new(name,options)
    end

    def process_rules(collection)
      collection.each do |row|
        rules.sort_by(&:priority).each do |rule|
          rule.run(row)
        end
        row.valid!
      end
    end

  end

  ## Helper Classes

  class Rule

    attr_accessor :priority
    attr_accessor :name

    # proc to test
    attr_accessor :validate

    # if valid
    attr_accessor :success


    # if invalid
    attr_accessor :fail

    NO_OP = lambda {|o| true }

    def initialize(name, options={})
      self.name = name
      self.priority = options[:priority] || 10
      self.validate = options[:validate] || NO_OP
      self.fail = options[:fail] || NO_OP
      self.success = options[:success] || NO_OP
    end

    def run(data)

      if validate.call(data)
        success.call(data)
      else
        fail.call(data)
      end

    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Cool; thanks for following up. Hope it works out okay--I've done a few really simple "rules engines" like this, and for many things, they're perfectly adequate.

Answer (score 1):

By comparison to the other existing Ruby rules engines, Ruleby seems like the most actively maintained:

- [Rools](http://rools.rubyforge.org/)
- [Ruby Rules](http://ruby-rules.codehaus.org/)

However, the **[Wongi Engine](https://github.com/ulfurinn/wongi-engine)** looks promising and may become what you need.

Comment: Not much happening with Ruby Rules by the look.

Comment: BTW the ruby-rules code I moved here https://github.com/michaelneale/Ruby-Rules as codehaus is no more (I haven't touched it in years, and its basic compared to the others).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps look at Wongi, as Stratus3D suggested. From a first glance it looks nice and has a good intro. I will test it out on a more complex testcase the next few weeks.

Rools on the other hand seems to be unmaintained (rubyforge page is dead, all the forks i found seem to be dead as well).

Answer (score 0):

Ive been playing with Ruleby for a few weeks on and off and its not too complicated to use, although where I added complications is using a massive case statement to programmatically load rules into the engine.

Once you understand stuff like facts are persistant in the engine & that each subsequent run doesn't just assess the facts you just put in but the facts you asserted previously as well it is pretty straight forward. Not a fan of how blackbox some of it is though when I get a runtime error its an absolute pain to troubleshoot (as I currently am with one part).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about the wongi-engine gem (https://github.com/ulfurinn/wongi-engine). It is based on the Rete algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm/) and has a syntax similar to what you are looking for.